# Get primitive value from Object extends Number?

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to make a class that can process subtracting, adding, updating for number with given type (anything that extends Number).

```
public class DynamicNumber<T extends Number> {

    private T number;

    public DynamicNumber(T number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void add(T number) {
        this.number += number;
    }

    public void subtract(T number) {
        this.number -= number;
    }

}
```

This won't work and throws the following exception:

> The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) (T, T)

This is because you can't use that operator for objects, and only on primitive values.

My question is how can I get the primitive value of the given object without knowing it's exact type, but just knowing it extends Number?

Comment: What if the Number is a BigDecimal?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with the current design without the interface `Number` having declared methods for those operations (`add()`, etc), which don't exist.

Comment: Which primitive value? `Number` declares `xValue()` for all numerical primitive types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T always extends Object, never a primitive. You can use instanceof and then cast to the object that extends Number. After that - if the object represents a primitive - you can use it using auto unboxing or using an explicit conversion. There is no way around this.

Comment: Technically, you could make `T extends Integer`, and the `+` operator would work with values of type `T`. (Because `Integer` is final.)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis But how will that work with Double an so on?

Comment: I think the remark of Sotirios is explaining what happens if you narrow down from Number to Integer, e.g. in a subclass.