# Store Long[] and Integer[] in the same HashMap using Generics

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I need to store arrays of different types of numerical data in a `HashMap`. Each array is a measurable variable such as temperature and I need to store the variables name and unit with the array so I made the class below:

```
public class Variable <T> {

    public T[] array;
    public String name;
    public String unit;

    ......etc

}
```

I want to be able to save `Integer[]`, `Double[]` and `Long[]` which is why I used the generic `<T>`. I have tried using `public Number[] array` instead but this does not let me save different types.

I have tried to store these in a `HashMap<String,Variable<Number>> map` using:

```
Variable<Long> temperature = new Variable<Long>();
map.put(temperature.name, temperature);
```

but I get the error:

```
The method put(String, Variable<Number>) in the type
HashMap<String,Variable<Number>> is not applicable for the arguments
(String, Variable<Long>)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461667/get-primitive-value-from-object-extends-number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) to help you:

```
Map<String, Variable<? extends Number>> map = new HashMap<>();
Variable<Long> varLong = new Variable<>(new Long[]{5L});
map.put("long", varLong);
Number number = map.get("long").array[0];
System.out.println(number.doubleValue());
```

Prints out: `5.0`

Answer (score 4):

Even though `Long` is a subclass of `Number`, `Variable<Long>` is not a subclass of `Variable<Number>`. This operation simply does not work with generics.

With a `HashMap<String,Variable<? extends Number>>`, you would be able to `put()` a `Variable<Long>`. You would not be able to retrieve it as such without an unsafe cast though, since the retrieved type would be `Variable<? extends Number>`.

Comment: Would it work if Variable generic was T extends Number?

Comment: @BenBeri it would if you had defined T somewhere.